# Why do I get different results using withMutations?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Am I misunderstanding its purpose or how it works?

```
var menuItems = Immutable.List.of(
  { parent_id: 0, id: 1 },
  { parent_id: 1, id: 2 },
  { parent_id: 1, id: 3 }
);

var results1 = menuItems
  .filter(function(menuItem) { return menuItem.parent_id === 1; }) // Filter out items with parent_id = 1
  .sort(function(childA, childB) { return childA.sort_order - childB.sort_order; }); // Sort them by sort_order

var results2 = menuItems.withMutations(function(list) {
  list
    .filter(function(menuItem) { return menuItem.parent_id === 1; }) // Filter out items with parent_id = 1
    .sort(function(childA, childB) { return childA.sort_order - childB.sort_order; }); // Sort them by sort_order
});

console.log(results1.size); // 2
console.log(results2.size); // 3
```

My understanding is that they would yield the same results, but that `withMutations` would be faster due to the chaining of operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood `withMutations`. The point of it is to give you a temporary playground where you can actually change the list instead of creating copies.

An example would be:

```
var results2 = menuItems.withMutations(function(list) {
  list.shift()
});
```

In your code, you use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) inside `withMutations`. Filter creates a new array and does not modify the original array, so your `withMutations` does nothing.

I think you would be better off just not using `withMutations` at all. If at some point you think "this would be so much easier if I could just modify the array instead of making copies", you can turn to `withMutations`.

Comment: Bonus: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/196#issuecomment-74131152
In a future version Immutable will throw an error when you try to do what I did